# Если в поле TextField ничего не написано, нужно при нажатии на кнопку "Ответить" не переходить на следующее View

Tags: ios, ios7

Если в поле TextField ничего не написано, нужно при нажатии на кнопку "Ответить" не переходить к следующему вопросу.Как это сделать?

Код перехода к следующему вопросу

```
if 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:completedLvl forKey:@"levelReached"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    [self questions];}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: ну давайте тогда я отвечу: ничего для этого делать не надо, просто оставьте все методы пустыми и при нажатии на кнопку ответить ваше приложение не будет переходить к следующему вопросу.

Comment: `[self questions];` это переход?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предложил бы вынести `[self questions];` в конец, чтобы не писать два раза, и там же, проверять, что в textField ничего не введено. И перенес `textField.text = nil` туда же. В зависимости от того, какой результат ожидается, этот код, можно поставить в самый верх.

```
if (usersHighestLevel == 0 && [textField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]){
    usersHighestLevel = 1;
    NSString *completedLvl = @"0";
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:completedLvl forKey:@"levelReached"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
} else if (usersHighestLevel == 0 && ![textField.text isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    usersHighestLevel = 1;
}

if(textField.text.length != 0) {
    [self questions];
    textField.text = nil;
}
```

Либо, если при пустом textField ничего не хотите делать, то в самом начале функции:

```
if (textField.text.length == 0) {return;}
```